# React Native Navigation: I renamed two files to swap them and the code. Example renamed 1 to 2 and 2 to 1. React native navigtion messing up now

Tags: reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

React Native Navigation: I renamed two files to swap them and the code. React native navigation messing up now. I had two files Register 4 and Register 5. I then renamed Register 4 to Register 5 and Register 5 to Register 4. React native navigation is now operating as if I did not make the change. It renders Register4 as if it was Register5 and does not register the new Register4 that i added renamed.

Register4 is supposed to be a form for a password and Register5 is supposed to be a form for a phone number.

Here is the App.js with the nav stack

```
const OutsideLayout = () => {
  return(
    <InsideStack.Navigator>
        <InsideStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}/>
        <InsideStack.Screen name="Register" component={Register}/>
        <InsideStack.Screen name="Register2" component={Register2}/>
        <InsideStack.Screen name="Register3" component={Register3}/>
        <InsideStack.Screen name="Register4" component={Register4}/>
        <InsideStack.Screen name="Register5" component={Register5}/>
        <InsideStack.Screen name="Register6" component={Register6}/>
    </InsideStack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, (user) => {
      console.log('user', user);
      setUser(user);
    })
  }, [])

  return (
  

  <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
  {user ? (
     <Stack.Screen name='Inside' component={InsideLayout} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
     ) : (
      <Stack.Screen name='Outside' component={OutsideLayout} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
     )
     }

  </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>


      );
  }
```

Here is my register 4

```
onst Register4 = ({navigation, route}) => {
const[password, setPassword] = useState("");



    return(
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.container}
        behavior="padding"
      >
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>

        <Text> Password</Text>
        
        <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="password"
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        />

        </View>
  
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={navigation.navigate("Register5", {firstName: route.firstName,
                lastName: route.lastName, DateOfBirth: route.DateOfBirth, Username: route.Username,
                Password: password}
              
            )}
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
          >
            <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Next</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>

    

    );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    inputContainer: {
      width: '80%'
    },
    input: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      paddingHorizontal: 15,
      paddingVertical: 10,
      borderRadius: 10,
      marginTop: 5,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
      width: '60%',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginTop: 40,
    },
    button: {
      backgroundColor: '#0782F9',
      width: '100%',
      padding: 15,
      borderRadius: 10,
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    buttonOutline: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      marginTop: 5,
      borderColor: '#0782F9',
      borderWidth: 2,
    },
    buttonText: {
      color: 'white',
      fontWeight: '700',
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    buttonOutlineText: {
      color: '#0782F9',
      fontWeight: '700',
      fontSize: 16,
    },
  });

export default Register4;
```

Here is my Register5

```
const Register5 = ({navigation, route}) => {
    const phoneInput = useRef(null);
    const phonenumber = useRef(null);
    const [fphonenumber, setFphonenumber] = useState('');
    const setValid = useRef(null);
   

    const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null);
    const [verificationId,setVerificationID] = useState('');
    const [code,setCode] = useState('');


    



    const sendVerification = () => {
      const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(FIREBASE_AUTH);
      phoneProvider
        .verifyPhoneNumber(fphonenumber, recaptchaVerifier.current)
        .then((vid) => {
          setVerificationID(vid);
          setFphonenumber("");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // show an alert in case of error
          alert(error.message);
        });
      }
      


      //Also check the wether the phone number is already in the database

        const confirmCodeAndUpdateUser = async (verification, authcode) => {
          const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verification, authcode);
          const {user} = await signInWithCredential(FIREBASE_AUTH, credential)
            .then(() => {
              setCode("");
              var user = FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser

              updateProfile(user, {
                displayName: route.firstName + " " + route.lastName
              }
              )

              
              }).then(() => {
              
              var user = FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser

                updatePassword(user, route.Password).then(() => {}).catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error)})

                var database_ref = Database.ref();

                var user_data = {
                  full_name: user.displayName,
                  date_Of_Birth: route.DateOfBirth,
                  username: route.Username,
                }

                database_ref.child('users/' + user.uid).set(user_data);

              })
            .catch((error) => {
              // show an alert in case of error
              alert(error.message);
            });
      }



    return(
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.container}
        behavior="padding"
      >
        
  
        <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal 
            ref={recaptchaVerifier}
            firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
            attemptInvisibleVerification={true}
        />

        {
          !verificationId && (

            <><View style={styles.inputContainer}>





              <Text> Phone Number</Text>
              <PhoneInput
                autoFocus={true}
                ref={phoneInput}
                style={styles.input}
                defaultCode="US"
                placeholder="999-999-9999"
                autoFormat={false}
                onChangeText={(number) => {
                  phonenumber.current = number;
                } }
                onChangeFormattedText={(number) => {
                  setFphonenumber(number);
                } } />
            </View><View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  disabled={!phonenumber?.current}
                  onPress={() => {
                    console.log(phonenumber.current);
                    console.log(route.password)

                    setValid.current = phoneInput.current?.isValidNumber(phonenumber.current);
      

                    if (setValid.current != true) {
                      alert("Phone Number is invalid. Please try a different number.");
                    } else {
                      sendVerification();
                    }


                  } }
                  style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
                >

                  <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Send Verification Code</Text>



                </TouchableOpacity>

              </View></>
        )}
        
        {verificationId && (
          
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>

          <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          
            placeholder="0000000"
            keyboardType='number-pad'
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setCode(text);
              console.log
            }}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              console.log(code);
              confirmCodeAndUpdateUser(verificationId, code)
                }}
            style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
          >

            <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Confirm Verification Code</Text>
            


          </TouchableOpacity>
          
        </View>)}
```

Comment: please mention the imports of modules in the code snippet , most probably it is a import mismatch

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid! It was definitely a import mismatch!!!!! Wow. I appreciate the help a ton always good to get out of the tunnel vision and get out of the though box.